# Convert bytes into human readable format (GWT)

Tags: java, gwt

This is a code to convert bytes into human readable format,

```
public static String humanReadableByteCount(long bytes, boolean si) {
    int unit = si ? 1000 : 1024;
    if (bytes < unit) return bytes + " B";
    int exp = (int) (Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(unit));
    String pre = (si ? "kMGTPE" : "KMGTPE").charAt(exp-1) + (si ? "" : "i");
    return String.format("%.1f %sB", bytes / Math.pow(unit, exp), pre);
}
```

The problem  is this does not work with GWT and throws:

```
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 20: The method format(String, double, String) is undefined for the type String
```

Is there a fix for this or another way to have this working?

Note the method is in GWT Client code.

Comment: What version of Java are you running that code with?

Comment: works for me ... Are you sure you are not importing some other class named `String`?